# FAILED: SemanticException Generate Map Join Task Error: Failed to generate new mapJoin operator by exception : Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: hive, type-conversion, union-all

I am doing a union all as following:

```
 insert overwrite table T3 select * from
 ( 
   SELECT cast (c1 as decimal(6,3)) as c1, c2
   FROM T1
   [WHERE conditions]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c1, c2
   FROM T2
   [WHERE conditions]
 );
```

c1 in T2 is calculated which is double where c1 in T1 is string.

When I cast c1 in T1 to double; there is the following error:

> FAILED: SemanticException Generate Map Join Task Error: Failed to
>   generate new mapJoin operator by exception : Index: 0, Size: 0

This table (output of the above query) will be inserted into another table where c1 column is double.

Comment: Strangely, there are neither joins nor lateral views or other operators which possibly can be converted to MapJoin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using view and this is probably where the join is.

Try to disable MapJoin as a workaround as suggested [**here**](https://hivemall.incubator.apache.org/userguide/troubleshooting/mapjoin_task_error.html):

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

Or materialize view before using in the query (load into the table).